# Can manually entered influencer addresses be run through Loqate at scale?

Tags: export-to-excel, street-address

In the past couple of months we have clients where we ingest all their addresses of influencers into Traackr, but it's a known issue that only addresses gathered thru studios export properly for the brand to do shipping labels (i.e. exported by column).  Frustration brands have is one core value of having them input is not usable and they have to combine multiple spreadsheets, split columns, etc...

Is there a way for us to run the addresses manually entered through loqate specifically for clients that harp on this pain point?

Clients try to export campaign lists of influencers and most are not formatted properly for shipping product to influencers with only those gathered via Studios exporting properly, which creates a lot of manual work for clients.